# How to do a deep search of object from a given string

Tags: javascript

I would like to split the `str` (dot seperated) and look inside an object tree, if the values exist.

To keep it simple, I have just create a simple object, but I would like it to be a deep search.

I just need the logic not necessary a working code, just a direction on what I need to do inside the exists to, check recursebly if `person.name.first` does exist with a `boolean` value `true || false` to be returned as the final answer.

```
var str = "person.name.first";

var arr = {
  person: {
    name: {'first':true ,'last' : true },
    age : true
  }
}

function exists(){
   ...
}
exists(str,arr);//true === exists, false === does not exist
```

Comment: #dupo it's slightly similar, but I just wanted to check if exists true or false. Not to get the value/reference.

Comment: working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e84pT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
function exists(str, arr) {
  var parts = str.split('.');
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(parts[i])) {
      arr = arr[parts[i]];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```